# How to add custom strong params in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I want my server to update a model parameter (layout_is_public) when a controller update action is called. The parameter should not be updated by users directly though.

My controller strong params:

```
def allowed_params
  params.require(:payload).permit(:name, :layout_id)
end
```

My before_action in the same controller:

```
def correct_layout
  if allowed_params[:layout_id].present?
    puts allowed_params.merge(layout_is_public: false).inspect

    # puts output is as expected:
    # => <ActionController::Parameters {"layout_id"=>1, "layout_is_public"=>false} permitted: true>

    allowed_params = allowed_params.merge(layout_is_public: false)
  end
end
```

I have no idea how to update my allowed_params to include the newly generated parameter though.

I'm also not sure whether this action should really be performed in the controller or the model itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Note: The layout_is_public variable is just set to false here for briefness.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you can also try this: -

```
private

def allowed_params
  ap = params.require(:payload).permit(:name, :layout_id)
  ap[:layout_is_public] = 'false' if params[:payload][:layout_id].present?
  ap
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly assign the strong parameter. Assign it to variable and merge the parameter.

```
   def correct_layout
      if allowed_params[:layout_id].present?
        puts allowed_params.merge(layout_is_public: false).inspect
        # puts output is as expected:
        # => <ActionController::Parameters {"layout_id"=>1,  layout_is_public"=>false} permitted: true>
        allowed = allowed_params
        allowed_params = allowed.merge(layout_is_public: false)
      end
    end
```